# How to make a picturebox to blink

Tags: vb.net, winforms, timer, picturebox

I'm downloading a file and at the end, I'm letting a picturebox blinking for couple of ticks.
At the end of the blinking, the picturebox should hide itself.
I'm using this code:

```
ReadOnly timerblinking As New Windows.Forms.Timer
dim blinking as integer
Private Sub mClient_DownloadFileCompleted(sender As Object, e As AsyncCompletedEventArgs) Handles mclient.DownloadFileCompleted

       Label2.Text = "Downloaded"
       Label2.Refresh()
       blinking = 0
       timerblinking.Interval = 500                                                           
       timerlampeggio.Enabled = True                                                           
       AddHandler timerblinking.Tick, AddressOf Timer_tick

   End Sub
Private Sub Timer_tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

      blinking += 1
       Rapid.PictureBox2.Visible = Not Rapid.PictureBox2.Visible
       If blinking= 5 Then                                                                                 '
           timerblinking.Stop()
           Rapid.PictureBox2.Visible = False
       End If
   End Sub
```

It does its work for the first time, but starting from second download completed, it just show the picturebox without blinking..I tried to put blinking=0 if blinking=5 (obviously after stopping the timer) but it does the same thing.
How can I let it blink also after the first time? Thankas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In each Button.Click event, you're adding a new handler to the `Timer.Tick` event.
Each timer the Timer is restarted, all event handlers are called in the same interval, hence the Control Visible property is set true/false concurrently multiple times.

This of course has a not so nice effect: it may just disappear, or appear and disappear *randomly*, depending on the timer frequency (interval).

You can test this writing to the Output pane, from the Tick handler, each time you click that Button and restart the Timer:

```
Private Timer1 As System.Windows.Forms.Timer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer

Private Sub someButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles someButton.Click
    AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Console.WriteLine("Timer Ticked")
    Timer1.Stop()
End Sub
```

And you'll see, in the Output pane, this:

```
Timer Ticked

Timer Ticked
Timer Ticked

Timer Ticked
Timer Ticked
Timer Ticked
```

Subscribe to the `Tick` event once, in the Form Constructor (or `Form.Load` event):

```
Public Sub New()
    AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
End Sub
```

Remove the Handler and dispose of the Timer when the Form closes:

```
Private Sub SomeForm_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosed
    RemoveHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf Timer1_Tick
    Timer1.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! That's useful!

Answer (score 0):

On a side note, if you change `ReadOnly` to [WithEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/withevents), then you can get rid of the `AddHandler` statement and switch to a [Handles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause) clause on the end of your `Tick()` event:

```
WithEvents timerblinking As New Windows.Forms.Timer

Private Sub timerblinking_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerblinking.Tick

End Sub
```

Then you don't run into problems with the same method being fired multiple times for a single event.